# Unable to install WordPress backup from live to local

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, content-management-system

I have taken backup from live WordPress site and installed locally using xampp. After setting db and WordPress files i unable to see the website. It is asking me to install fresh WordPress. Attached snapshot. Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance.
[image: capture 1]

[image: Capture 2]

Comment: Hi if username,password, root, and host is ok then please also cross check the prefix below in wp-config.php file

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the url correctly in database. you can do using 2 ways

1) Change url using mysql query, so run below queries in to phpmyadmin

> UPDATE TABLE wp_options SET option_value = "YOUR LOCAL SITE URL" WHERE option_name = "siteurl"
>
> UPDATE TABLE wp_options SET option_value = "YOUR LOCAL SITE URL" WHERE option_name = "home"

2) Open the sql file in any editor and find the live site url with local url and save nad import in to database.

Comment: Also, modify the .htaccess file to refer to your local wp root folder correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should install the WordPress locally; then you should import the backup created. The below are the steps followed

1. Export Website Content with the Export Tool
2. Create a New Local WordPress Installation
3. Import Website Content with the Import Tool

Please have a look at the below link for more detailed information.
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/move-wordpress-xampp/

Let us know if this helped. Thanks

Comment: Agreed. Plugins like wp clone work really well for site migration too, taking care of all those configuration for you.